# Same answer by same user posted in two questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-answers

There are two almost-identical questions<sup>1</sup> which both have two practically identical answers posted by the same user: [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649842) and [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680660) (posted 3 days after the first answer).

As of now those answers have respectively 39 and 160 upvotes with no downvotes.

From his [reputation history](https://stackexchange.com/users/125727/kcoppock?tab=reputation) we can see that in those days (10-13 Jan 2011) the user had enough reputation (from 3047 to 3177) to be able to flag or directly close the second post as duplicate and enough experience (almost one year on SO) to know that this is not the way how Stack Overflow works.

**The Question**:
Is this considered good behaviour?

I've not raised a *"normal"* flag<sup>2</sup> nor a custom flag<sup>3</sup>, but I think this is not a good thing on SO.

One or more users have upvoted both answers and he gained twice of reputation from one single answer (from 0 to 390 of undeserved reputation)

---

***<sup>1</sup> -*** Posted by **two** different users.
***<sup>2</sup> -*** Given the high votes, they could have been taken as an audit.
***<sup>3</sup> -*** Mods who have handled my custom flags tended to leave upvoted posts as they where.

Comment: Welp, voting to close that first one as dupe... It's not considered good behaviour to duplicate knowledge, no.

Comment: @Kyll I would have voted the other way around, the other question is better IMHO. Consider merging?

Comment: @rene I voted this way since the second one had more views / SEO juice. Yeah, merging seems very appropriate, good call! Raise a mod-flag?

Comment: I'm not thrilled by that dupe @Ironman nor by its answer...

Comment: @Kyll I'm even wondering when we switched from moderating new crap to getting on terms with old stuff.

Comment: So what to do now @rene? Do I have to raise a custom flag? Someone else can do this? I'm only at 641 rep and even if I have raised 2000+ flags I feel that I will not be heard...

Comment: Do know that I normally don't touch positive scored, high-viewed posts. I can spend all my flags on new crap. If this post is an example of your 2000+ flags I wouldn't have high hopes...

Comment: @rene why? I posted here because I felt that if I had rised any flag this would have not been heared, what's wrong with my post/help-request?

Comment: @CliffBurton in general - posting duplicate answers (and in this case - while it uses the same code - at least the OP has added an addendum more specific to the issue) is frowned upon. I'm not sure what you want a mod to do - one post can be closed as a dupe of the other if appropriate and you don't require a mod for that.

Comment: @JonClements I already raised custom flags for notifying dupe answers by a low-rep user and the sententia was that the duplicate answer was removed (I suppose because those answers had no more than 7 upvotes) but this is a new case for me, one user with 3000 rep points posting two identical answers on two identical questions in just a 3-days range. Custom flags cannot be discusses but here, so I posted this question hoping for some mod to handle the case without annoying with a custom flag that could have be declined

Answer (score 11):

First of all the questions are at fault. They are possible duplicates. Given the fact that duplicate search has quirks at best, and the lack of research by most OP's, dupes get asked and answered.

The two questions you brought up are not blatant duplicates. One just wants to get the sizes from the element. The other wants that too, to fit it to the outer element. It would for example mean that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4681587/578411) would make no sense on the first question.

Maybe, we don't know for sure, the user that answered realized that and therefore decided to re-use his answer. Instead of a blatant copy they linked to it and copied over the code. After that they maintained both copies.

To answer your direct question:

> *Is this considered good behavior?*

If with *this* you mean the exact case you brought up I would say I see not much wrong with it. This doesn't mean that this applies to other blatant copies of answers. It needs careful judgement on a case by case basis.

A simple duplicate flag on one of the questions would have been enough in this case. I don't see why you would want to destroy the value of positive scoring and accepted answer on a highly viewed question.

I personally don't care about undeserved reputation as that means I have to think about users instead of posts.

Answer (score 4):

Vote to close one of the questions as duplicate of the other. (Assuming the two questions are closely related enough to be considered as such.)

Then, if you care to do so, leave a comment to the answerer to the effect that this would have been a preferable course of action for her/him to take, rather than posting a duplicate answer.

Don't get mods involved unless this behaviour is a rampant problem on this particular user's part.