# How to handle repeated answer reposting

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation

I came across two questions which should probably be marked as duplicates. Both questions had the same answer (with minor modifications) posted by a 20k+ rep user. After doing some research I read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327523/same-answer-by-same-user-posted-in-two-questions) and decided to flag one of the questions as a duplicate of the other and move on.

After about a day I was checking on the flag and decided to look at the user's profile. I immediately found a different case of the same answer being used on at least 4 different questions, some of which had not been active for years.

It looks like this user is answering one question, searching for old questions that the answer might apply to, re-posting the answer, and then making a minor edit to the question so that it gets visibility. The questions are fairly obviously duplicates and the fact that the user appears to be searching for questions similar to the one the original answer was posted on makes me think they are likely aware of the fact that they should be marked as duplicates.

In the answer that was posted on 4 different questions received a combined 300+ positive votes which is over 3k reputation. The re-posted answers are  very high quality answers that took a lot of effort, and obviously people are finding them helpful, but it appears the user is purposefully gaming the reputation system by pasting the answer on old questions instead of marking them as duplicate.

Does this matter? If the answers are helpful in each case should I just leave everything alone? I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions) on StackExchange which lead me to believe some action may need to be taken but I figured I would ask here before doing anything other than flagging as duplicate.

Also, I purposefully didn't name the user or give examples as I don't want to draw any attention to them if people decide this is ok.

Comment: Gaming the system to post high-quality answers.  Evil dude.  The automatic alert that mods get for such duplication are generally used to squash project spam.

Comment: @HansPassant I kind of agree. If people are finding it useful is it really that bad to post it in multiple places? But I figured I would ask. Does the fact that the automatic alerts appear to have been ignored mean the mods agree as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you come across this happening, flag one of the answers for moderator attention and describe what's going on; if you have room, link to some of the duplicate answers to help expedite the mods' work.

With that being said, there is a mechanism in place to detect *exact* duplicates of answers, so it's possible the mods will be made aware of it automatically. (And I think there is a bot in the SOBotics group that monitors for duplicates, too)

If the questions you see being answered are duplicates of each other (which is likely if this user is posting the exact same answer to each one), flag those as duplicates, too. The point of the duplicate system is to direct people to the best set of answers and avoid this exact scenario where information is scattered and repeated.

If the questions were all closed as duplicates and this user only answered the source question, he'd still ostensibly have received all those upvotes anyway, so it's not like the user could argue they would lose out on rep by answering the appropriate way.

Comment: Yes, please, mark all questions as duplicates because someone through a hammer is a handy tool and it fix all the things.