# How fair is it for a moderator to decide alone to delete a post without any comment on why the post is deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, moderators

First off, I want to be clear this post is not against the moderator. Rather, I would like to know on what basis did the moderator delete the post single-handedly and how can you judge that the moderator has considered measures before deleting the post?

My posts are usually deleted without any comments nor any mistakes. I understand that posts from ChatGPT are banned, and copying another post without referencing them leads to deletion of the post, but why is a post which is purely written based on experience, referenced from official API, tested and made sure that it would work perfectly, deleted without letting the post creator know why?

How can the fairness of this be measured? Is it fair to delete good, genuine posts written from the creators?

At the least it should be made compulsory to comment the reason of deleting the post before it is deleted.

I am talking about the following sample posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75641669/13431819
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74751585/13431819

---

Another observation: moderators delete posts or decline the undelete of the post within some hours or at the maximum a day, on the contrary, for the valid edited question. When i raise to reopen the question, it is never reopened; it’s just in the queue. It’s almost a week now that I have raised the re opening of this answer. Why is it so?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957684/13431819

Comment: For the second linked question it seems like you are answering questions instead of voting to close as duplicate (In fact you have posted quite a similar answer today as well) You seem to understand / believe that they are duplicates since you also mention in your answer "_For more details refer :_"

Comment: Your first link looks ok, I don't think diamond moderators should delete well received answers on personal whims. Can't say the same about the second though

Comment: The first linked question is probably deleted due to the same reason as well. I found this similar (but more detailed) [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130316/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-in-flutter/75148843#75148843) which basically is a repost of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093907/how-to-get-data-from-firestore-document-fields-in-flutter/75150729#75150729). Please don't repost your answers to multiple questions, if they have the same answer close them as duplicates.

Comment: *"Another observation, moderators delete posts or decline the undelete of the post within some hours or at the max a day , on contrary, for the valid edited question, when i raise to reopen the question, it is never reopened, its just in the queue. Its almost a week now, that I have raised the re opening of this answer. Why is it so ?"* Moderators do not handle reopen requests.  They are handled by [a review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen) of normal users.

Comment: FYI you retracted (selfclear) your own custom flag for undeletion. Moderators never saw it. Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPVXb.png Your claim in the question is incorrect.

Comment: I didn't get you @SamuelLiew. I had given credits in my post previously aswell a moderator deleted saying it is not sufficient. So i made sure i deleted all the reference from others post and removed credits and claimed for reopen of the question , which never passed through

Comment: That was for your statement that "(you) have raised the re opening of this answer" with the third linked answer you added above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957684)

Comment: "At the least it should be made compulsory to comment the reason of deleting the post before it is deleted." How are moderators supposed to handle the sheer extra effort from this? Posting comments that don’t leave room for misinterpretation takes considerable time, and moderators would have to post tons of them.

Comment: E.g., [10 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13431819/bouncybits) with an average interval of 6 minutes. That looks like a typical ChatGPT workflow or at least you didn't write all of that yourself (***significant*** differences in writing style). Where did you copy it from?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Well i tested it myself and made sure it worked, and then found all the similar questions and based on the questions i answered.

Comment: I dont know if that feature exists in the chatGPT, that i post all 10 questions to it and it give similar answers without any explanation, just the code, c'mon now.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I dont want to explain myself, if you see it as i have copied it from chatGPT, you'll certainly see every of my handwritten answers as **significant** different answer. So there is no much to talk. I just remember the famous quote from Red Notice , IT DOESN'T MATTER WHAT YOU DO,ONLY MATTERS WHAT THEY THINK YOU'VE DONE.

Comment: "and then found all the similar questions and based on the questions i answered" - don't do that. If questions are so similar that the same answer works for all of them, you should vote to close the others as duplicates, *not* add the same answer for all of them.

Comment: I didn't say it came from ChatGPT, just that looked like it (this answer rate and writing style has been seen on multiple Stack Exchange sites over the last few months). Regular plagiarism usually has a much lower rate. Unless you are very good at it, you can't fake ***two completely different writing styles***. For instance, it is nearly [impossible to learn to not leave out articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74920813/) if they aren’t in your native language. Another reason could be a shared Stack Overflow account, used by more than one person. Or a purchased account.

Comment: @oguzismail *"Your first link looks ok, I don't think diamond moderators should delete well received answers on personal whims."* - there are so many things we shouldn't do. For example, there is no way you can prove that the deletion decision was made on a whim so I wouldn't know what you were hoping to achieve by making such a suggestive statement. The most common cases I see on meta when such a topic comes up is: 1) oops, I made a mistake and 2) well, here is a list of things you didn't think about but I can see before I made that decision. But never "yeah, I felt like abusing my power".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We single-handedly delete posts in conformance with site rules, because our delete votes are binding and usually only one moderator handles any given issue.

We do discuss things among us when the resolution is not clear-cut, and we do often oversee each other's work in order to catch mistakes with as little impact on the affected user as is reasonably possible.

However it would be completely intractable to seek internal consensus for every single action that we take and/or to leave a comment under each and every post we delete. Those numbers are in the thousands, daily.

Moreover, one of the reasons we might skip commenting is when a user has been *repeatedly warned* about issues with their posts. As a matter of fact, **we have commented under several of your posts already** (links for 10k users: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript/75602734#75602734), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java/75602595#75602595), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript/75602506#75602506), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393146/firestore-collection-query-as-stream-in-flutter/75273398#75273398), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980222/flutter-convert-from-querysnapshot-to-a-future-listmapdynamic-dynamic/75150286#75150286), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911384/how-to-get-data-from-cloud-firestore-where-user-uid-equal-to-document-id-in-flut/75150060#75150060), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter/75149656#75149656) and there's more).

I shall also note these links prove that multiple moderators have looked into your posts, and opted to delete them.

So to be honest, your claims here come across as a bit disingenuous. In case you still have any doubts, please:

- **[don't rehash existing answers without adding anything new](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers)**
- **[don't post identical or nearly-identical answers to different questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366321/how-to-handle-repeated-answer-reposting)**

For that matter, there is also a review queue, Late Answers, accessible by users with >=500 reputation whose specific purpose, among others, [is to delete duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers), emphasis mine:

> Delete (or recommend deletion of) answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are link-only, **or are duplicates of other answers**.

As for [the last link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957684/13431819) you posted — which by the way has a quite clear comment from the moderator who deleted it (spoiler: it was me) — you did flag your post to ask us to undelete it, but *you retracted your own flag* before we could see it. As mentioned by [Samuel Liew in this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423541/how-fair-is-it-for-a-moderator-to-decide-alone-to-delete-a-post-without-any-comm#comment949351_423541):

> FYI you retracted (selfclear) your own custom flag for undeletion. Moderators never saw it. Proof: [i.stack.imgur.com/sPVXb.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPVXb.png) Your claim in the question is incorrect.

Beside the fact you seem to be confusing reopening questions with undeleting answers, we literally did not see that flag because you retracted it. Obviously the answer was never undeleted. If you wish to bring it to our attention again, please flag it and *wait for the flag to be handled*.