# How to review copied answers on different questions

Tags: discussion, review-queues, multiple-answers

Today I found multiple answers in the Late Answers queue with the same content, obviously all written by the same user. 
<s>If you look at his last five answers from today, you see what I mean:</s>

- [How to get Directory while running unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204091/how-to-get-directory-while-running-unit-test/52949053#52949053)
- [How to get path of project from test project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747584/how-to-get-path-of-project-from-test-project/52949142#52949142)
- [How to get path in project folder from unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401539/how-to-get-path-in-project-folder-from-unit-test/52949209#52949209)
- [How to avoid DeploymentItem? I need to deploy a file at once for all tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388121/how-to-avoid-deploymentitem-i-need-to-deploy-a-file-at-once-for-all-tests/52949517#52949517)
- [NUnit DeploymentItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378276/nunit-deploymentitem/52949597#52949597)

I have to say, the answers kind of fit and they are all adjusted a bit to the original questions, but this still feels like spamming to me.

If the same answer fits multiple questions, shouldn't they be marked as duplicates instead then? Any guideline on how to review this kind of answers would be appreciated.

---

If you like to read - I found some other posts on meta regarding similar discussions:

- [Why are duplicate answers deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336000/why-are-duplicate-answers-deleted)
- [Same answer by same user posted in two questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327523/same-answer-by-same-user-posted-in-two-questions)
- [Two different questions by the same user with the same answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286999/two-different-questions-by-the-same-user-with-the-same-answer)
- [Duplicate flagged posts - is re-use of existing answers OK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250087/duplicate-flagged-posts-is-re-use-of-existing-answers-ok)

---

**Results:**

As a lot of you guys recommended, I **raised a custom flag**. It took a while, but now the moderators decided that (in this case), it was indeed **helpful**. It looks like all his answers have been deleted by now.

However, I want to give credit to [Tezra](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6893866) and [DonQuiKong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7322095). IMO they also mad a good point that similar answers can still provide value. 
In the Future, I'm going to value the answers more by themselves and will raise a custom flag if I don't see the value.

Comment: btw: is meta the right place to ask this kind of question?

Comment: I would flag a moderator with a custom flag

Comment: Yes, meta is the right place to ask this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no, don't, stuff like this is flagged automatically.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Identical answers are flagged automatically, but these answers aren't entirely identical. Not sure if these would get auto-flagged.

Comment: @S.L.Barth is correct, those posts are not auto-flagged as the post body are not exactly the same, so just custom flag one of them with links to the others.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Even if this were auto-flagged, I don't believe there is any harm in manually flagging as well. Mods can see and handle all flags on a post simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand on DonQuiKong with a quick alternate example.

Given the questions

- In Java, How do I programmatic make sure my HTTP request is valid?
- How do I use a REST API from Java?
- How can I convert HTTP response headers to a map using Java?

I can answer all of these questions with the same answer (with minor insignificant changes) along the lines of "Use an HTTP library like x".

The same answer can be valid for multiple questions, but obviously not all answers to these questions will satisfy all of them. Likewise, the value of the answer will vary by question. For example, if I only want to do validation, bringing in a whole library might be overkill. So the only way to properly do quality control for the answer per question, is to duplicate it. Using comments to link is unstable, and prevents down-voting the suggestion; And its score on one question provides no insight into how relevant it is to the current question.

---

So ultimately when we see a copy-pasted answer, we have to ask these questions

- Is it properly cited? (does it need to be?)
- Does this answer the question it's posted on?
- Can its flaws be salvaged with edits?

Basically, the same set of questions we would ask when looking at an answer that was written by scratch for this question. So for all intents and purposes, treat the answers as they stand on their own (including any possible plagiarism).

Comment: thx, your example made DonQuiKong's answer more clear to me! From that POV, duplicate answers do have a value that is hopefully high enough to justify them against the cataloge argument from yivi.

Answer (score 1):

The same answer is often the correct answer to multiple questions.  If it is, and the questions differ, I see no problem with this.  Someone googles for his/her question, reads the answer and goes away happy.

As an example, I've written four small OpenXml apps now.  The answers to about half the (often very different) questions I see about OpenXml is "download the OpenXml Productivity tool from the Microsoft site, save two copies of a Word/Excel/etc file, one with the feature you are talking about, and one without it, and then diff the two files in the tool" (ok, sometimes, just reflecting the code (within that same tool) will find the answer).

But, the questions this answer answers are all over the map.  But, I really think that repeating this answer adds value.

Comment: Would you mind writing up a fuller description of this for [my discussion on Meta SE about whether duplicate answers implies duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q)?

Comment: A tangent on the Open XML example: This information should *not* be an "Answer", only a comment. Using the Productivity Tool is a suggestion on how to *find* the answer, but it's not an answer...

Comment: Often times, it is only a comment.  Occasionally, I'll be more descriptive and make it an answer.  Often times, the answer/comment decision is based on the wording of the question (for example, if the question is "how to I figure out how to do this").  But, essentially, the answer to an awful lot of OpenXml questions is "download the tool, do this, do that, and look at what the tool points out as the answer".  You quickly learn this once you do any OpenXml work

Answer (score -2):

From the discussion in the comments, I think I need to make a few assumptions clear:

If the answer doesn't add anything to the existing answers, it might be vlq or otherwise need mod attention.

If the answer is vlq anyways, flag it as vlq / vote to delete, etc.

But under the **assumption** that the answer does not have any other problems that would merit deletion/flagging/downvotes, and the only problem with the answer is, that it **almost** duplicates another answer, the following applies. If it's not fine even if it weren't a duplicate, deal with it accordingly.

**If the answer is fine on it's own, it does not get "not fine" just because there is an almost identical answer somewhere.**

In my opinion, if the answer is an actual answer to the question and doesn't violate copyright (aka copied from wikipedia), it's valid.

Yes, the question should be marked as a duplicate. But then, suppose the answer wasn't copied from somewhere, would that be a reason to delete it? No, we don't delete answers on duplicate questions. Because they still have a value.

It might feel like cheating, but let's just look at any of the answers and forget the others for a moment.

Does the answer help answer the question?

If yes, why on earth would we want to delete it? Sure, the answerer took a shortcut by recycling an old answer of theirs. In a short timeframe. Multiple times.

**That's a good thing!**

Multiple people now have an answer on their question which helps them. Isn't that all that counts? Isn't 99% of the content of this site a more or less copy of some text book, tutorial or programming class? Do those answers suddenly lose their value if you find out how the answerer knew and that they didn't reinvent the wheel, but merely looked it up?

What would we achieve by deleting those answers? We would delete a useful answer because it wasn't a lot of effort writing it. That's ridiculous! If I more or less cite something somebody once told me which answers the question, that's not a lot of effort. Should those answers be deleted? Should only "original" answers be allowed? That would be impossible.

Therefore, **mark the question as duplicate** and then forget about it.

Comment: I don't agree with some points you state in your answer. You say it's a good thing if a user posts almost identical answers to multiple questions. In theory that may be ok, but not in practice. Most of such answers that I've seen were low-quality answers or would have needed major edits to be tailored enough to answer the question adequately. Also you say that 99% of the content of this site is copied from other sources. That's not true. I wrote every one of my posts by myself and *if*I copied something from another source, I made sure that I make it clear (using quote blocks etc.).

Comment: @Filnor you misunderstood (or I misrepresented, w/e) my point. If the answer is vlq, flag it as vlq / vote to delete, etc. But if the answer is fine on it's own, it does not get "not fine" just because there is an almost identical answer somewhere.

Comment: The content here is "copied" because it could be found elsewhere to. I'm pretty sure a lot of the questions here could be answered by "read chapter x, book y" or read tutorial z. That's not a bad thing. The answers you wrote are "copies" of something you learned somewhere someday. The user asking the question would have to search for that content while you can provide it off the top of your head. if you had it written down somewhere already, would you write it down again just so you don't copy yourself? Of course not. So why not copy a previous answer of yours instead?

Comment: @DonQuiKong: you've got some interesting points here. Yes, every answer is somewhat copied and theoretically he is providing value. But here, he is answering questions, that (4/5) have already accepted answers and some of them (2/5) have already more than 10 other (highly upvoted) answers. It is unlikely that someone will scroll down that far. Therefore, it's unlikely that he is providing value for others. I don't want to blame him to be selfish, but here it feels like a way of gathering reputation (I've been there - I expect it from others)

Comment: Duplicating content is not fine, and dilutes the catalog. If the objective is to help the user, just post a comment pointing them to the answer that you wanted to copy. You then help the user without posting duplicate content.

Comment: @yivi comments aren't meant to be permanent so that can't be a solution.

Comment: Exactly my point. If what you want is help one particular user, you can use a non permanent solution. As a permanent solution, **you do not post duplicated content, but link it instead**.

Comment: @Skandix if it's unlikely someone will go there, it's unlikely he'll get rep for it. But just look where that would get us. Forbidding answers on questions that are solved? If the answer doesn't add anything to an existing answer, it might be vlq or otherwise obsolete -**but that's a different problem** it has nothing to do with whether the answer is a copy of another answer or not.

Comment: @yivi so you propose the user should have written an answer like "see this answer of mine which might get deleted someday and make this answer obsolete too and furthermore needs the following adaptions to fit this question: ..." doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: If the linked answer was likely to be deleted, then it was probably not that great to begin with. And what's protecting the duplicated answer and not the original? This doesn't make any sense. The objective is build a quality repository of q&a, not post the same answers again and again. If they need _some_ adaptation, well, you can point that in the comments if you are feeling helpful. That's great. You help one user without diluting the catalog's quality. But the catalog is more important than one single user.

Comment: @yivi sometimes content gets deleted for whatever reasons. I disagree. Every question here can be answered by posting something from somewhere with some adaption. That's how knowledge transfer works. That's how SO works. Someone knows something that can be adapted to answer a question somebody else has. The objective is to answer questions, not to build a huge lookup table with links to links and comments and links to more links.