# User has posted the same answer twice

Tags: support, flags

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340728/how-to-convert-json-dataframe-to-other-dataframe/58485389#58485389) in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue (and I recommended deletion). However, when I went to the actual link, I noticed that the user had posted the exact same answer (as far as I can see) twice - the second coming just about half an hour after the first.

I thought about a custom "Requires Moderator Attention" flag but was uncertain: First, I've had a few flags declined lately (not disputing, these decisions, BTW). Second, I know mods are very busy, so maybe there's a better way for the "Community" to deal with this.

I also thought that, by raising this question on Meta, the Community will possibly be able to handle it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not plagiarism but it is very similar to it. So a lot of the guidance how to deal with plagiarism also applies here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered

Comment: @Gimby - No, it's not plagiarism, as it the same user! But I see that both are now gone - so, job done, I guess!

Comment: for the nex time: this existing meta post about the same topic suggests going ahead with the custom flag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375675/how-to-review-copied-answers-on-different-questions

Comment: Those were both questions posted in the answer box. Just vote to delete (both).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sure, vote to delete will get them gone - but is there a case here for some sort of flag (Spam, maybe?) so that the user gets noticed as a possible/potential offender?

Comment: Two deleted, heavily downvoted posts will already contribute significantly to a possible future answer ban if he continues to treat SO like a forum; no further action is needed - just review as normal

Comment: @Adrian this is not spam, there's nothing being promoted.

Comment: Also, both posts aren't the same, one contains the error this person has with their code. So they might have added another post by accident, because they either tried to edit and failed or didn't know editing is possible. Still flagable as NAA since both are questions, not answers, but nothing big to worry about.

Comment: @Gimby: Double-posting is nowhere near on the same level as plagiarism just because they look the same. It just looks like the user is unaware of the edit button.